# Laravel Redirect not existing Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have this code in `App/Exceptions/Handler.php` in its `render()` method:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
    switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {
        // not found
        case '404';
            return redirect()->route('index');
            break;

        // internal error
        case '500';
            return redirect()->route('index');
            break;

        default;
            return $this->renderHttpException($e);
            break;
    }
} else {
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

But the problem is that when I go to `localhost:8000/vendor`, I am not redirected. I get the following response:

> **The requested resource /vendor was not found on this server.**

I want all urls that result in 404 Not Found to be redirected to my homepage.

Comment: I just tried doing what you are doing (based on what you posted as code) and it's working fine for me. Probably there's something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: The code in my post is working but when I tried /vendor, there's a response "Not Found" but if random string, It will be redirected to homepage

Comment: Do you use `php artisan serve`?

Comment: Yup, but I am using MAMP too for my db

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that some packages publish assets to `public/vendor`, so it is a **folder** and depending on the setup of your web server, folder might **be** or might **not be** available for listing (`Options +Indexes` for some web servers). Most cases it is not allowed to list its contents so you get `404 Not Found` or `403 Forbidden`.

To redirect in Apache, put the following in `.htaccess` file located in `public/`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://your-website.com/
```

If you are using nginx, in your config file place:

```
error_page 404 /;
```

For the built-in PHP server (`php artisan serve` eq), you should do it manually, somehow... Hopefully, you are using it only for development of your application and for production, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: So what can I do to catch it, so that when the user tried to type it in the url, the user will be redirected to homepage.

Comment: oh, so I need to configure my .htaccess, I'll try that tomorrow maybe. Btw thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll handle it with 404 route, in route file (*I want to catch all that is not existing in my routes. I want them to be redirected to my homepage.*)

```
Route::fallback(function ()
{
    # To Specific Controller
    return Redirect::to('homeController'); # ('/') if defined 

    # To Specific View
    return response()->view('custom.file.path', [], 404);
});
```

Comment: IMHO, suggesting another approach for solving a certain problem is not quite valuable to @OP.

Comment: Route::fallback is not working for me. Thanks for answering btw.

Comment: where did you add that ??

Comment: It is not working because `vendor` is a folder within `public/`. He gets a 404 of the webserver not a 404 handled by laravel (missing route).

Comment: @DeadManAlive in my routes.php, btw the code in my post is working. I just want to catch/redirect if the user type /vendor in the url

Comment: @IvankaTodorova oh, so what do I need to do so that I can catch it.